# How do I share an array of a custom type between different views using SwiftUI?

Tags: arrays, swiftui, swift5, environment

I am trying to create a database  for different cameras. I have used a struct to create a type that has a few different variables like Make, Model, Shutter Speed, crop factor ext.. (although I have removed most to make the code smaller here)

I want to display the names of the cameras in a list on the landing page and have a sheet to add the cameras to the array, which is where I plan to store the cameras information. I can’t for the life of me figure out how to create an environment object (or something similar) that is an array of a custom type that can be edited and viewed on multiple different views.

As I’m sure is obvious I am very new to coding and am having trouble finding any solutions that I can easily follow. Perhaps I’m missing something very obvious but I just don’t know what to do. Is it possible to create a shared Array of a custom type or am I going about this wrong?

The Landing Page including the list view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    //starts with the AddCameraView not being shown
    @State private var showingSheet = false
    
    @State public var cameraArray = [CameraStruct]()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            List{
                //for each camera in the array join the manufactuerer and model to create a name and dispaly it in the list
                ForEach (cameraArray, id: \.id) { camera in
                    Text("\(camera.camManufacturer)" + " " + "\(camera.camModel)")
                }
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Cameras")
        .toolbar{
            Button{
                showingSheet.toggle()
            } label: {
                Label("Add Camera", systemImage: "plus")
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
                AddCameraView()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

The Sheet with the custom form.

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddCameraView: View {
    
    //allows the sheet to close when told
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    
    @State public var cameraArray = [CameraStruct]()
    
    
    //starts with the form being empty
    @State private var camManufacturerInput = ""
    @State private var camModelInput = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView{
            VStack{
                //creates the form for information
                Form{
                    Section(header: Text ("General Info")) {
                        TextField("Camera Manufacturer", text: $camManufacturerInput)
                        TextField("Camera Model", text: $camModelInput)
                    }
                }
            }
            .navigationTitle("Add Camera Details")
            .toolbar{
                ToolbarItemGroup(placement: .navigationBarTrailing) {
                    Button("Save"){
                        //creates a variable using the new type camera struct
                        var camera = CameraStruct(id: UUID(), camManufacturer: camManufacturerInput, camModel: camModelInput)
                        
                        //adds the camera to the first position in the array
                        self.cameraArray.insert(camera, at: 0)
                        dismiss()
                    }
                    //all text fields must be filled filled in to save
                    .disabled(camManufacturerInput.isEmpty || camModelInput.isEmpty)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
struct AddCameraView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AddCameraView()
    }
}
```

The Custom Struct I am using

```
import Foundation

struct CameraStruct: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id: UUID
    var camManufacturer: String
    var camModel: String
}
```

I have followed a good number of online tutorials including StateObjects and EnvironmentObjects but didn't seem to get any closer to where I wanted to be. Often it would result in creating a new class with values already within it whereas I want to start from a completely blank app to build up from.

Comment: You're creating a _new_ array on `AddCameraView`. If you want the _same_ array, one way to achieve that is with a `Binding` (https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/what-is-the-binding-property-wrapper). You could also store the array in a `@Published` variable inside an `ObservableObject` and pass it around via property or `EnvironmentObject` as you mentioned: https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/how-to-use-environmentobject-to-share-data-between-views

Comment: You can use a ObservableObject `ViewModel` and add the array in a `@Published` property. Then you can observe the `ViewModel` from different structs(Views).

Comment: I believe I have followed the instructions for the Environment object link provided by @jnpdx but I keep getting a fatal error within my ForEach saying 'No ObservableObject of type (the type name I used)' I can't see any typos or anything. Is the way I'm creating my sheet meaning it isn't able to view an Environment Object?

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to have more than one view see a view model as I couldn't have the extension contain multiple views, maybe its just me but I couldn't get it to work following this tutorial. https://www.hackingwithswift.com/books/ios-swiftui/introducing-mvvm-into-your-swiftui-project

Comment: It’s not possible to see what’s going wrong unless you include your attempt here. Can you edit your question with what you’ve tried?

Answer (score 1):

Use `let` for read access or `@Binding var` for write access, which essentially is a pair of get and set closures for the state. In your case you need write access so it's like this:

```
.sheet(isPresented: $showingSheet) {
    AddCameraView(cameraArray: $cameraArray)
}
```

```
struct AddCameraView: View {
    @Binding var cameraArray: [CameraStruct]
```